# Объединить массив в один

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите возможно соединить массивы в один, у меня заказ записывает в одну таблицу order, а товар в order_product.

`order`

```
            Array
    (
 [0] => Array(
    [order_id] => 52
    [firstname] => test
    [lastname] => tst
    [email] => Test
    [telephone] => test
    [payment_address_1] => Отделение №1: ул. Гагарина,22
    [payment_method] => Новая почта
    [date_added] => 2017-03-15 15:51:44
    [date_modified] => 2017-03-15 15:51:44
    )
)
```

`order_product`

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
        (
        [order_product_id] => 281
        [id_order] => 52
        [name] => Тапочки
        [model] => Закрытые
        [quantity] => 1
        [total] => 25.00
        [oll_total] => 25.00
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [order_product_id] => 280
        [id_order] => 52
        [name] => Носки
        [model] => Закрытые
        [quantity] => 1
        [total] => 20.50
        [oll_total] => 20.50
    )
```

Возможно получить массив такова вида

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array(
            [order_id] => 52
    [firstname] => test
    [lastname] => tst
    [email] => Test
    [telephone] => test
    [payment_address_1] => Отделение №1: ул. Гагарина,22
    [payment_method] => Новая почта
    [name] => Тапочки,Носки
    [oll_total] => 25.00+20,05
    [date_added] => 2017-03-15 15:51:44
    [date_modified] => 2017-03-15 15:51:44
)
```

)

Comment: `$order[0]['name] = implode(',', array_map(function($p){ return $p['name];}, $order_product))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант 1. Запрос в базу. Пример для MySQL:

```
SELECT o.*, GROUP_CONCAT(op.name SEPARATOR ', ') AS name, SUM(op.oll_total) AS oll_total 
FROM order_table o
LEFT JOIN order_product_table op ON op.order_product_id = o.order_id
GROUP BY o.order_id
```

Вариант 2. Цикл в PHP, если у вас 2 массива

```
$result = [];
foreach ($orders as $key => $order)
{
    $result[$key] = $order + ['name' => [], 'oll_total' => 0];
    foreach ($order_products as $key2 => $product)
    {
        if ($product['order_product_id'] == $order['order_id'])
        {
            $result[$key]['name'][] = $product['name'];
            $result[$key]['oll_total'] += $product['oll_total'];
        }
    }
    $result[$key]['name'] = implode(', ', $result[$key]['name']);
}
```

Готовой функции нет.
В вашем конкретном случае я бы выбрала вариант 1.

Comment: сложный у вас вариант на пхп вышел. двумя отдельными циклами решать надо, а не вложенным

Comment: @teran вы правы, можно оптимизировать, если ключами $result сделать order_id

Comment: Спасибо @Elena второй способ как раз  подошел

Answer (score 0):

Для объединения массивов можно использовать `merge()`
Что-то типо такого:

```
var arr1=[1,2,3];<br>
var arr2=["a","b","c"];<br>
$.merge(arr1, arr2);
```

Comment: Лучше использовать `array_merge_recursive()`, так как в массивах есть одинаковые ключи

Answer (score 0):

всё более чем очевидно

```
$order['products'] = $order_product
```

Comment: вы уверены, что у вас после сего действа в `$order['name']` будет  `тапочки,  носки` ?

Comment: @teran не понял вопрос я просто добавляю масив в индекс масива `order` так как связь же один ко многим, один заказ и много продуктов. Причём тут вообще `$order['name']? а если надо удалить товар из заказа?

Comment: в конце вопроса у автора приведен пример желаемого результата. где в `$order` добавляются поля `name` и `oll_total` сформированные на основе `$order_product`

Comment: @teran И это значит что нельзя натолкнуть автора на более правильное и удобное решение, а не кастыль?

Comment: дак вы сначала ответьте, на то что спрашивается, а потом наталкивайте на другие решения. Не зная конкретной сути решаемой задачи, нельзя с уверенностью сказать, что это костыль.

Comment: вы же не утверждаете что `group_concat` это непонятный костыль в mysql, и надо выбирать полный набор данных? иногда надо просто склеить строки, а не таскать кучу данных

Answer (score 0):

Просто сложите массивы:

```
         $arr1 = array(
                    [
                    "order_id" => 52,
                    "firstname" => "test",
                    "lastname" => "tst",
                    "email" => "Test",
                    "telephone" => "test",
                    "payment_address_1" => "Отделение №1: ул. Гагарина,22",
                    "payment_method" => "Новая почта",
                    "date_added" => "2017-03-15 15:51:44",
                    "date_modified" => "2017-03-15 15:51:44 "
            ]

     ) ;

    $arr2 = array(
            [
                    "order_product_id" => 52,
                    "id_order" => 52,
                    "name" => "Носки",
                    "model" => "Закрытые",
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "total" => 25.00,
                    "oll_total" => 25.00,
            ],
            [
                    "order_product_id" => 280,
                    "id_order" => 52,
                    "name" => "Тапочки",
                    "model" => "Закрытые",
                    "quantity" => 1,
                    "total" => 25.00,
                    "oll_total" => 25.00,
            ],
    ) ;


    $result = $arr1 + $arr2;
```

Результат:

http://prntscr.com/ekltaa

Comment: вы читаете вообще что автор  спрашивает, в конце приведен вид желаемого массива, при чем тут сложение?

Comment: @teran и действительно, прошу прощения